# How to simplify $\frac{3+\log_{p}3}{5^2}=\frac{-5+\log_{p}5}{3^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've found this problem in my algebra book and still can't get the right way how to solve it.

The problem is as follows:

Find $\log_{p^5}\left(3^5\times 5^3\right)$ from:

$$\frac{3+\log_{p}3}{5^2}=\frac{-5+\log_{p}5}{3^2}=\frac{10}{3^3+5^3}$$

The alternatives given are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
 1.& 2\\
 2.& 1\\
 3.& \frac{1}{2}\\
 4.& 3\\
 5.& \frac{1}{3}\\
 \end{array}$

So far what I tried is the following, but I must say that this process was tediously slow and in the end I couldn't get the value of $p$.

What I began was to obtain a relationship between the functions:

$\log_{p}3=\frac{5^2\left(10\right)}{3^3+5^3}-3$

$\log_{p}5=\frac{3^2\left(10\right)}{3^3+5^3}+5$

Then I went to the question so what it is being asked is:

$\log_{p^5}\left(3^5\times 5^3\right)$

This is reduced to:

$\log_{p^5}\left(3^5\times 5^3\right)=\frac{5}{5}\log_{p}3+\frac{3}{5}\log_{p}5$

So all what it was left was to replace the first two expressions in the later:

$\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(\left[5\right]\left(\frac{5^2\left(10\right)}{3^3+5^3}-3\right)+\left[3\right]\left(\frac{3^2\left(10\right)}{3^3+5^3}+5\right)\right)$

$\frac{5}{5}\log_{p}3+\frac{3}{5}\log_{p}5=  \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{5^3\left(10\right)-15\left(3^3+5^3\right)+3^3\left(10\right)+15\left(3^3+5^3\right)}{3^3+5^3}\right)$

$\frac{5}{5}\log_{p}3+\frac{3}{5}\log_{p}5=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{10\left(3^3+5^3\right)-15\left(3^3+5^3\right)+15\left(3^3+5^3\right)}{3^3+5^3}\right)$

$\frac{5}{5}\log_{p}3+\frac{3}{5}\log_{p}5=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{10\left(3^3+5^3\right)}{3^3+5^3}\right)$

$\frac{5}{5}\log_{p}3+\frac{3}{5}\log_{p}5=\frac{1}{5}\left(10\right)$

$\frac{5}{5}\log_{p}3+\frac{3}{5}\log_{p}5=2$

Therefore the answer would be $2$. However as mentioned using this procedure did not required to find $p$ however I wonder if attempting to find $p$ would yield an integer or would be a right way to go?. The method which I used consumed a lot of time. Does it exist a workaround to be easier or faster?. I'd appreciate someone could help me with this!.

Comment: You can make working it out easier by letting $x = \log_p(3)$ and $y = \log_p(5)$

Comment: $p$ won't necessarily be an integer, and you do not need to worry about finding $p$ in this problem.

Comment: It's lot easier if we separate and simplify $\frac 35(3^2\frac {10}{3^3 + 5^3} +5) = \frac {3^3*2}{3^3 + 5^3} - 3$ and $\frac 55 (5^2\frac {10}{3^3 + 5^3} - 3) = \frac {5^3*2}{3^3 + 5^3} - 3$ separately.  If you do them separately you get $(\frac{5^3*2}{3^3 + 5^3}-3)+(\frac {3^3*2}{3^3 + 5^3} + 3)$ and that's almost trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log_p 5 = 3^2\frac {10}{3^3 + 5^3} + 5$

we have $5 = p^{3^2\frac {10}{3^3 + 5^3} + 5}= p^{5.5921052631578947368421052631579}$

So $p = \sqrt[5.5921052631578947368421052631579]{5} = 1.3334977373599735351181643891153$.

I'm pretty sure that's a dead end.

The algebra is *nasty* but there is a lot of canceling if you do it right so it's not so bad.

....

Well, $\log_p 3 = 5^2\frac {10}{3^3 + 5^3}-3$

And $\log_p 5 = 3^2\frac {10}{3^3 + 5^3} + 5$.

And so $\log_{p^5}(3^5\times 5^3) = \log_p 3 + \frac 35\log_p 5=5^2\frac {10}{3^3 + 5^3}-3 + \frac 35(3^2\frac {10}{3^3 + 5^3} + 5)$

$= 5^2\frac {10}{3^3 + 5^3}-3 + 3^3\frac {2}{3^3 + 5^3} + 3$

$= \frac {5^3*2}{3^3 + 5^3} + \frac {3^3*2}{3^3 + 5^3}$

$= \frac {2}{3^3 + 5^3}(5^3+ {3^3})$

$ = 2$

Comment: Well at least It seems that my answer was right. As I suspected the result would be irrational and going that route would led a dead end as you mentioned. I didn't spoted what you did until the answer was posted. But I'd like to point out that I also thought in other simplication but more or less leads to what you found. But we do agree that the way to go is to just solve for each logarithm individurally and append them together in the question, the route for that final simplication is up to the solver's desire. In other words a matter of taste.